# jquery search results filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, sphinx

im building a search engine with php/sphinx/jquery and i have most of it working except for the filtering the search results. the search results aren't filter submitted rather, all the results are displayed then im trying to use jquery to hide the unmatched results when a checkbox is clicked on.

i created a fiddle for it here http://jsfiddle.net/LEZAh/

what works:
checking a box and have the corresponding element show, and when another box is checked add it to the allowed boxes to show.

what doesn't work:
when you have more than one checkbox checked and you uncheck one of them, the corresponding element does not show.

sorry for the bad explanation but the fillde will speak for its self thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as an addition to the excellent post above (mrtsherman, ahren), the last line of your else statement was causing the problem. A quick and dirty solution would be:

```
    //$(".ni-search"+checks).show(); //this was the offending line

    $("#cat_"+$(this).attr('id')).hide(); //instead of showing everything just hide what was clicked
```

I've run this in your fiddle successfully as well.

Comment: Nice catch, my first thought was to not even try and figure out why his code didn't work because I knew it could be done more simply. I'm sure he will appreciate an answer that shows how close he was with his own code though!

Comment: how would i make all the items come back when none are selected?
http://jsfiddle.net/LEZAh/5/

Answer (score 1):

I've simplified your click function.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
   $('.search-option input').click(function(){
      var inputs = $(".search-option input");
      var products = $(".ni-search");

      products.each(function(i){
         if(inputs.eq(i).is(":checked")){
            $(this).show();
         }else{
            $(this).hide();
         }
      });
      if(products.length == inputs.not(":checked").length){
          products.show();  
      }
   });
});​
```

This assumes your results will all be in the same wrapper, and your checkboxes will also all be in the same wrapper.

[Link to updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LEZAh/2/)

Comment: much more simple, however i couldn't get it working on my page (it is a little more elaborate), but works great in the fiddle.
i elected to keep my code and use the fix that @Jeffrey Hogan suggested. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another simplified version of your script.

http://jsfiddle.net/LEZAh/4/

```
$('input').change(function() {
    //all checkboxes are unchecked, so show all
    if ($('input:checked').length == 0) {
        $('.ni-search').show();
    }
    else {
        //otherwise only show checked
        $('.ni-search').hide();
        $('input:checked').each(function(index) {
            $('.ni-search').eq(index).show();
        });
    }
});​
```